# use xsl:number incide if

Tags: xslt, if-statement, numbers, xslt-1.0

There is list

```
<nodes>
<node attr='1'/>
<node attr='0'/>
<node attr='1'/>
<node attr='1'/>
</nodes>
```

i need to apply-templates all nodes and count it:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select='nodes/node'>
<xsl:if test='@attr=1'>
<xsl:number/>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

but a haz in result not 123, result is 134. How to fix it in xslt-1.0? There is another way to set numbers to it? position() not help, and

```
<xsl:apply-templates select='nodes/node[@attr=1]'>
<xsl:if test='@attr=1'>
<xsl:number/>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

not help to =(((

Comment: What number you want to print? On XML, there is no number related to 123 or 134

Comment: Not sure why you would want 123, or what that would indicate?

Comment: You want to have an incrementing index over the elements found by XPath `nodes/node[@attr=1]`, correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you have an error in your XSLT

```
<xsl:apply-templates select='nodes/node'> 
   <xsl:if test='@attr=1'> <xsl:number/>     
   </xsl:if>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

You can't have an **xsl:if** within an **xsl:apply-templates**. You need a matching **xsl:template** and put the code in there...

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="nodes/node" />

<xsl:template match="node">
   <xsl:if test='@attr=1'>
      <xsl:number/>     
   </xsl:if>
<xsl:template>
```

In fact, you could do away with the **xsl:if** here, and just have the test in the template match

```
<xsl:template match="node[@attr=1]">
    <xsl:number/>     
<xsl:template>
```

But to answer your question, you probably need to use the **count** attribute on the **xsl:number** element to count only the elements you want

```
<xsl:number count="node[@attr=1]"/>
```

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="nodes/node"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="node[@attr=1]">
      <xsl:number count="node[@attr=1]"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="node"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to you XML, the result is 123

Answer (score 2):

This says 123 - is this what you were after?

```
<xsl:for-each select="nodes/node[@attr='1']">
  <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Is it possible to achieve the same with <xsl:key/> ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not quite clear what are you trying to achieve. I presume you need to count the number of nodes that have attribute set to 1. In that case, use the [count](http://zvon.org/xxl/XSLTreference/Output/function_count.html) function:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(nodes/node[@attr='1'])" />
```

In case you need to output a position of the desired node *inside the subset matching the condition*, then `for-each` will be probably the way to go:

```
<xsl:for-each select="nodes/node[@attr='1']">
    <xsl:value-of select="position()" />
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: But that would give you 3, whereas I think they seem to want 123. No, I have no idea why either?

Comment: @Woody: 123 would be like numbering the matched nodes. i.e. the first matched node has number 1, the second matched node has number 2, and so on. i.e. the same thing that you can specify in square brackets to denote which one of the found nodes you want to get back.

Comment: Agreed there are reasons you may want to number the nodes, it is just not described well in the question what the actual reason is.